# Copy files between folders in the same S3 bucket by using cp

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy files between folders in the same S3 bucket by using the following:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder1 s3://bucket/folder2 --recursive
```

It halts after copying some files.

```
Completed xxxx part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

Sometimes it copies 2k sometimes 4k. I have more than 30k files.

Is there a limit to file copy? How can I copy large number of files?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be failing, but as a tip.... You could use `aws s3 sync`, which will only copy files that are new/updated since the last sync. This would probably allow a restart if the copy fails.

Comment: The ability to recursively copy files is a feature of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), not the underlying API call. Therefore, the CLI app is making repeated API calls to copy each file. You might be experiencing network issues that cause a failure after a period of time. Can you try it via a different (more reliable?) Internet connection? BTW, the data doesn't download/upload -- all the copying happens within the Amazon S3 cloud, but the API calls still need to traverse the Internet.